# Ubuntu Server 16.04 GUI (xfce4)

Tags: 16.04, server, xubuntu, xfce, vnc

I want to install xfce4 on my Ubuntu Server 16.04.
The Problem is that the Server stopped working with the Command `apt-get install xubuntu-desktop`

So i read that i can install xfce4 `apt-get install xfce4` manually and start it at booting.
So how can i do that?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "manually". It has to be done from the repositories with the apt-get command.

Comment: I want to install XFCE4 only. No Xubuntu. when i install xubuntu the System did not start.

Comment: What was the error on boot? Solving it might be easier than doing an uncommon installation. By the way, there is also [Xubuntu core](https://xubuntu.org/news/introducing-xubuntu-core/).

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - I loaded xrdp then xfce4, and it all works just fine.  Plus, I get the option at login on the console as to which desktop I want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "the Server stopped working with the Command apt-get install xubuntu-desktop" which is very strange, nevertheless `xubuntu-desktop` installs a complete *xubuntu* desktop on your system.  Not just *XFCE*.

If you want to install *XFCE* only and tweak everything manually, you need to install *Xorg* too and a display manager, like `lightdm` for example.

All three of them can be installed with this command:
`sudo apt-get install xorg lightdm xfce4`.

This will install the absolute basic *XFCE* on your system without any additional fonts or any kind of addditional mouse cursors for example.  You will have to install and tweak everything by hand afterwards.

Comment: Okay thanks, the mouse cursors are in the package xfce4-goodies i think.
I will try it.
and how can i start it with booting ? When i Install this PAckages, and restart my System.
I got a Ubuntu Unity Login Page.
Not an Xfce4.
When i try to log in, I got the message: failed to start session Thank you.

Comment: At the right side, just above where you enter your password, there are some kind of icon indicating which DE you will be loging in to. Click on this and you should be able to choose any of the installed DEs.